# Как заменить символы в файле по индексу

Tags: python

Есть файл наподобие

```
Victor Anton Stepan Marat
Nikita Aleksandr Anton Karim
```

Я знаю индекс начала и конца имени Anton в первой строке и мне нужно его заменить в файле вопрос как это сделать что-бы получилось например

```
Victor Vladislav Stepan Marat
Nikita Aleksandr Anton Karim
```

Comment: 1) Считать файл в список 2) Обработать список 3) Выгрузить список в файл

Answer (score 0):

Что в python можно делать со строками в контексте замен подстрок:

- Заменить подстроку по маске: `"Anton Maxim".replace("Anton", "Vlad")` -> `"Vlad Maxim"`
- Разбить строку на список по разделителю:

  ```
  s = "Anton Maxim".split()
  s[0] = "Vlad"
  s = " ".join(s)
  ```

  (Результат тот же)
- Разбить по символам:

  ```
  s = list("Anton Maxim")
  s = s[:0] + list("Vlad") + s[5:]
  s = "".join(s)
  ```

  (Результат опять же тот же)
  А вообще почитайте про методы строк - https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html

Answer (score 0):

Заменить по индексам начала и конца слова как-то так:

```
s = "Victor Anton Stepan Marat"
i1 = 7
i2 = 11
s1 = s[:i1] + "Vladislav" + s[i2+1:]
print(s1)

# Victor Vladislav Stepan Marat
```

Как прочитать и записать файл через `with open`, `readlines` и `write` не буду писать, это уж совсем основы.